# I am getting an "undeclared identifier" error in Delphi and I don't know why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am having troubles and am unsure as to why i am getting an "Undeclared Identifier" error in the following code:

```
procedure getword;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  randomize;
  randomwordnumber := random (20) + 1;
  randomword := wordlist [randomwordnumber];
  for i:=1 to length(randomword) do word:= word + '?';
  lblrandomword.Caption := (word);
end;
```

Also here is the exact error code:

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(138): Undeclared identifier: 'lblrandomword'
```

Thank-You in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only guess but `lblrandomword` probably is a `TLabel` on a form. You have to make `getword` a method of that form. Maybe like this:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lblrandomword: TLabel;
    //...
  private
    procedure getword;
    //...
  end;

procedure TForm1.getword;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  randomize;
  randomwordnumber := random(20) + 1;
  randomword := wordlist[randomwordnumber];
  for i := 1 to length(randomword) do word := word + '?';
  lblrandomword.Caption := (word);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can  pass the label to `getword` as a parameter (courtesy of  [Sebastian Proske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836111/sebastian-proske)).

Additional note: If there are no error messages regarding `randomwordnumber` and so on, these are probably global variables. This is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Or pass the label to `getword` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys, i just did as @SebastianProske stated and defined it in my parameters, it works perfectly now. Thanks also to you "Uli Gerhardt" for global variables tip!