# How to access a Label from a procedure inside a procedure in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, label, procedure

In my program, I have many procedures which I call by each other. In one of them I need to change the caption of a Label.

From that I get an error:

> Undeclared identifier: 'Label'

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850371/i-am-getting-an-undeclared-identifier-error-in-delphi-and-i-dont-know-why) is the reason for the error.

I don't know how to solve this, since I don't want to make all procedures part of the form or pass the Label through all procedures.

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
procedure Print(Display: );
var
  Text_Label:String;
begin
     Text_Label:=IntToStr(first_number_Int);
     Label_Display.Caption:=Text_Label;
end;

procedure number_press(number_pressed:String);
begin
     first_number_Str:= first_number_Str+number_pressed;
     Print();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   number_press('1');
end;
```

I'm already use `number_press(...);` in many Button Click Events and I'll use `Print();` many times in the code.

For help I'll be very thankful.

Comment: All controls on a form are effectively "global variables", at least within that form's unit and any other unit that `uses` that form's unit.  So `Print` can directly refer to `TForm1.Label_Display`.  Does that fit with your requirements?

Comment: Making the procedures part of the form class is probably the safest option in case there can be more than one instance of that form.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways you could handle this.

You could pass the Label around:

```
procedure Print(Label_Display: TLabel);
begin
  Label_Display.Caption := ...;
end;

procedure number_press(...; Label_Display: TLabel);
begin
  ...
  Print(Label_Display);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  number_press(..., Label1);
end;
```

You could use a callback with an anonymous procedure, eg:

```
type
  DisplayCallback = reference to procedure(NewCaption: String);

procedure Print(Label_Display: DisplayCallback);
begin
  Label_Display(...);
end;

procedure number_press(...; Label_Display: DisplayCallback);
begin
  ...
  Print(Label_Display);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  number_press(...,
    procedure(NewCaption: String)
    begin
      Label1.Caption := NewCaption;
    end
  );
end;
```

Or, if everything is in the same unit, just use the Form's global pointer:

```
procedure Print;
begin
  Form1.Label1.Caption := ...;
end;

procedure number_press(...);
begin
  ...
  Print();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  number_press(...);
end;
```

Comment: The last one is exactly what I needed

Comment: @christian: At least you think so, but you'll get into serious trouble when you start creating several instances at once in the future.

Comment: @Remy: Why not include the best practices approach: having `Print` as a method belonging to the form class?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't know really what you mean.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand because the OP specifically said "*I don't want to make all procedures part of the form*"

Comment: @christian if you ever need to have multiple object instances of `TForm1` alive at the same time, then using the global form pointer will no longer work, since it can point at only 1 object at a time. That is what Andreas is warning about.